# Not Able to Export inDesign CS6 Document to Full Screen Mode

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-cs6

I am using Adobe inDesign CS6 and I need to export the document to Adobe PDF(Print) in full screen mode (to open the PDF in full screen ) but I can not find any option for this!
Can you please let me know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Search all the settings for an "Initial view" option.

Comment: Thanks for reply but where should I look for this? I am not seeing any "Initial view" option on "Export Adobe PDF" Options!

Comment: Try changing the preset to something other than printing to see the view options - see [InDesign CC Tip: PDF Export View Options | Technology for Publishing LLC](https://tech4pub.com/2015/07/14/indesign-cc-tip-pdf-export-view-options/)

Comment: Search all sections.

Comment: Exporting a PDF for print is, surprisingly enough, not meant for PDFs destined to be viewed onscreen. Consider exporting as an Interactive PDF instead

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad this is working now!